# SuppressWarnings (unchecked) is working sporadically in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've been working through legacy code and trying to clean it up, and obviously from time to time you'll get warnings that you can't really do anything about other than suppress the warning.

Unfortunately, for some reason not all annotations of SuppressWarnings("unchecked") work, and when I go to run a build some methods throw the complaint that should be suppressed.

For example,

```
public class Foo extends Bar {

public Foo () {
    // Some code
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Object visit(Visitor v) { 
    v.accept(this);
}
//Other code omitted. 
}
```

Throws the warning when it comes to compiling of

```
Warning:(18, 19) java: visit(...Visitor) in ...Foo overrides <R>visit(...Visitor<R>) in ...Bar
  return type requires unchecked conversion from java.lang.Object to R
```

Oddly enough, when IntelliJ runs it's analysis in real time on the file, it reports no errors or warnings, this only pops up during compilation.
Additionally, I can remove the warning if I use the Suppression at the class level, however I don't want to use that solution since it'd be inappropriate for large classes.

Is anyone able to explain what's going on, and how best to resolve this?

Comment: In this case remove the `@SuppressWarnings` and specify the types: `public ... visit(Visitor<...>v)`; some generic type parameters seem to be missing, maybe also `Foo<R> extends Bar<R>`.

Comment: Your legacy code contains raw types. The `Visitor` class expects a type parameter, but none is given.